# Use alternative ports for MTA e-mail exchange

Tags: networking, email, mta

As an MTA, is it reasonable and does not it violate RFCs to connect to MX servers on ports other than tcp/25 (SMTP) for e-mail exchange?

Traditionally e-mail exchange goes on tcp/25, but ISPs block it for a long time to avoid spam.

I'd like to setup a proper MTA, but my ISP blocks tcp/25 as well. Is it a good practice to make my MTA software to connect to other standard/conventional ports like 2525, 587, 465 of any MX server?

Note, it's not MUA I'm asking about.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is it a good practice to make my MTA software to connect to other standard/conventional ports like 2525, 587, 465 of any MX server?

No. Most MX servers *will not expect* mail exchange on those ports.

Ports 587 and 465 have a different purpose – RFC 6409/8314 define them for "Message submission" from end user MUAs, and these ports almost always require authentication (even if the recipient is local).

Port 2525 is nonstandard; while you might find one or two servers accepting SMTP on that port, most of the time it will just do nothing (or even listen for something that isn't SMTP).

So if you cannot make outgoing connections to port 25, you will simply not be able to send mail to most domains. (Which is indeed the whole point of ISPs blocking this port...)

You can set up SMTP on a trusted server hosting company, then use that server as a "relay host" aka "smarthost" for your home MTA.

Answer (score 0):

Or just change your ISP. which allows incoming/outgoing connections and port 25.
Maybe I can help you, if you haven't found a solution so far. I can set up a relay for you on my server (port 25) to your MTA on any port. I would configure my server to work as a service proxy server and forward to your MTA server, and you only need to configure the MX recods on your domain.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).